# ReferenceError: Request is not defined. jest unit test fail

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, ts-jest

I have created the simple unit test but it's thrown error [image: ReferenceError: Request is not defined]

I don't think so it's related to Promise resolve or rejects.

here I added a code snippet. Let me know if you have any idea about that.
Your help really appreciated.
Thanks

**Code**

```
filterRowCol(Contxtdata): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let Obj: any = {};
      console.log("Contxtdata", Contxtdata);
      this.hasMasterContext = false;
      for (let i = 0; i < Contxtdata.length; i++) {
        if (Contxtdata[i].Perspective.indexOf("/") != -1) {
          let contextRow = Contxtdata[i].Perspective.split("/")[0].toLowerCase().trim();
          let contextCol = Contxtdata[i].Perspective.split("/")[1].toLowerCase().trim();
          console.log("Curent Row:", this.commonService.BodyJson.rows[this.commonService.Row].title);
          if (contextRow == this.commonService.BodyJson.rows[this.commonService.Row].title.toLowerCase().trim()) {
            if (contextCol == this.commonService.BodyJson.rows[this.commonService.Row].cols[this.commonService.Col].Title.toLowerCase().trim()) {
              Obj = {
                ID: Contxtdata[i].Id,
                index: i
              };
              console.log("ReturnOBJ:", Obj);
            }
          }
        }
        if (Contxtdata[i].Perspective.toLowerCase().trim() == "master") {
          this.hasMasterContext = true;
          this.masterObj = {
            ID: Contxtdata[i].Id,
            index: i
          };
        }
      }
      if (Obj.ID) {
        resolve(Obj);
      }
      else {
        resolve(Obj);
      }
    });
  }
```

**Unit Test case**

```
it('should closeChat', () => {
    const Contxtdata = [
      {
        Perspective: "Test4/Demo41"
      },
      {
        Perspective: "jk/pharma"
      },
      {
        Perspective: "pass/fail"
      }];
    spyOn(service, "BodyJson").and.returnValue(Promise.resolve({
      ID: 5,
      index: 0
    }))
    const data = component.filterRowCol(Contxtdata);
    console.log("data>>>>>>!!", data);
    expect(data).toBeTruthy();
  });
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74791368/3015545