# ReferenceError: Request is not defined when testing with React Router v6.4

Tags: typescript, react-router, react-testing-library

I am attempting to create unit tests using React Testing Library that click on React Router links to verify certain pages appear. I am using a very similar setup to the answer found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74399490/how-to-test-routing-logic-with-react-router-v6-and-testing-library). When I run the test I get `ReferenceError: Request is not defined`. Since I am using a RouterProvider I can not follow the React Testing Library docs exactly.

I have my routes set up in a dedicated file:

```ts
export const routes: RouteObject[] = [{
    path: '/',
    element: <AppWrapper />,
    errorElement: <PageNotFoundScreen />,
    children: [{
        path: '/',
        element: <FeaturedSearchScreen />
    },{
        path: 'auth',
        element: <AuthScreen />,
        children: [{
            path: 'login',
            element: <LoginForm />
        },{
            path: 'signup',
            element: <SignUpForm />
        }]
        },{
            path: 'dashboard',
            element: <DashboardScreen />
        },{
            path: 'search',
            element: <SearchResultsScreen />,
            loader: searchLoader
        } 
    ]
}];
```

I then create a memory router in my test file

```ts
const router = createMemoryRouter(routes, {initialEntries: ['/']});
const user = userEvent.setup();
render(<RouterProvider router={router}/>);
```

I am using an Outlet in AppWrapper to render all of the children.

### **Expected**

Tests pass

### **Results**

```
Vitest caught 1 unhandled error during the test run.
This might cause false positive tests. Resolve unhandled errors to make sure your tests are not affected.

⎯⎯⎯⎯ Unhandled Rejection ⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯
ReferenceError: Request is not defined
 ❯ createRequest node_modules/@remix-run/router/router.ts:2654:3
 ❯ startNavigation node_modules/@remix-run/router/router.ts:886:19
 ❯ Object.navigate node_modules/@remix-run/router/router.ts:784:18
 ❯ push node_modules/react-router/lib/components.tsx:74:16
 ❯ navigate node_modules/react-router/lib/hooks.tsx:211:7
 ❯ internalOnClick node_modules/react-router-dom/index.tsx:727:9
 ❯ handleClick node_modules/react-router-dom/index.tsx:385:9
 ❯ HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:4164:14
 ❯ HTMLUnknownElement.callTheUserObjectsOperation node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/generated/EventListener.js:26:30
 ❯ innerInvokeEventListeners node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:350:25
```

When I render the initial screen, I am able to verify all components, so I know my set up is generally working. It fails awaiting the new page header. Feel free to look at the entire code on this branch https://github.com/Thenlie/Streamability/tree/43-feat-test-suite

Comment: Since the router/components appear to render initially without issue I think the issue is with something that is rendered and doesn't manifest until the UI is interacted with. I'm almost certain the issue is with `export async function loader({ request }: { request: Request }): Promise<string> {` [SearchResultsScreen.tsx::14](https://github.com/Thenlie/Streamability/blob/43-feat-test-suite/src/screens/SearchResultsScreen.tsx#L14) where during the unit test `Request` it seems is undefined. I haven't an explanation now why though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I ended up needing to create a setup file that defines Request. I found this through the [React Router code](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/main/packages/router/__tests__/setup.ts)

```ts
import { fetch, Request, Response } from "@remix-run/web-fetch";

if (!globalThis.fetch) {
  // Built-in lib.dom.d.ts expects `fetch(Request | string, ...)` but the web
  // fetch API allows a URL so @remix-run/web-fetch defines
  // `fetch(string | URL | Request, ...)`
  // @ts-expect-error
  globalThis.fetch = fetch;
  // Same as above, lib.dom.d.ts doesn't allow a URL to the Request constructor
  // @ts-expect-error
  globalThis.Request = Request;
  // web-std/fetch Response does not currently implement Response.error()
  // @ts-expect-error
  globalThis.Response = Response;
}
```

This can then be referenced in the testing config file, for me `vitest.config.ts`.

```ts
import { defineConfig } from 'vitest/config';

// https://vitest.dev/guide/#configuring-vitest
export default defineConfig({
    test: {
        environment: 'jsdom',
        setupFiles: './src/__tests__/setup.ts',
        globals: true,
        watch: false
    }
});
```

Answer (score 15):

I solved it using 'jest-fetch-mock' (https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-fetch-mock)

For TypeScript/ES6 add the following lines to the start of your test case (before any other imports) in the `setupTests.ts` file.

```js
import { enableFetchMocks } from 'jest-fetch-mock'
enableFetchMocks();
```

Comment: For anyone looking to fix this in vitest, the instructions are *slightly* different but very clear [in the docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vitest-fetch-mock)

Answer (score 3):

The docs include [this paragraph](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/routers/picking-a-router#testing) regarding testing:

> Testing components that use React Router APIs is easiest with createMemoryRouter or  instead of the routers you use in your app that require DOM history APIs.
>
> Some of the React Router APIs internally use fetch, which is only supported starting from Node.js v18. If your project uses v17 or lower, you should add a fetch polyfill manually. One way to do that, is to install whatwg-fetch and add it to your jest.config.js file like so:

```
module.exports = {
    setupFiles: ["whatwg-fetch"],
    // ...rest of the config
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve it by installing the polyfills for Node ([Remix](https://remix.run/docs/en/main/other-api/node)):

```bash
npm i -D @remix-run/node
```

Then inside the test file installed the globals such as "fetch", "Response", "Request" and "Headers":

```
import { installGlobals } from "@remix-run/node";
...

installGlobals();
```

I did have also to install `whatwg-fetch` since `remix-router/node` have a dependency to the `fetch` global object and I am using jsdom as test environment but if your using node as test environment, You need not worry.

whole setup configuration file

```
import { RouterProvider, createMemoryRouter } from "react-router-dom";

import "@testing-library/jest-dom";
import "whatwg-fetch";
import { render, screen, waitFor } from "@testing-library/react";
import { installGlobals } from "@remix-run/node";

// This installs globals such as "fetch", "Response", "Request" and "Headers".
installGlobals();
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code works like charm but if you are looking for a more elaborated answer please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/77460901/2640467

```
// react-router-dom uses Remix router and since
// Remix router is failing for some reason around the Request obj
global["Request"] = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({
  signal: {
    removeEventListener: () => {},
    addEventListener: () => {},
  },
}));
```